# Is there a reason for an if statement followed by another to end the line with an 'and' operator (&&) in ruby?

Tags: ruby, if-statement

I'm trying to figure out why this works and whether it's a bad practice.

The following code will throw a *SyntaxError*:

```rb
if true &&
  puts "ok"
end
```

Though the following code will not, it will execute as expected:

```rb
if true &&
  if true
    puts "ok"
  end
end
```

I came across this while writing a ruby script with an **if** statement containing a big chain of conditions, so I put each one in a separate line and then I commented out the last one and executed the script. At the moment, I realized that the **if** statement ended with the **&&** operator. While I expected it to throw, I was amazed that it didn't because another **if** statement followed right after.

My ruby version is `ruby 2.2.6p396 (2016-11-15 revision 56800) [x86_64-darwin16]`.

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer? You don't want to see others?

Comment: I wanted to know _why_ and @ray's answer did just that. The first situation throws an error, because the && operator expects an expression. The second situation doesn't throw, because the if-statement is considered an expression.

Comment: @JoaoPestana: Except it is not about being an expression or not, it is about operator precedence. BTW, the same argument applies when you accept my answer: accepting an answer too early discourages people from providing an *even better* answer that may take them longer to write because they are putting in more effort. Or, they are simply in a different timezone and not even awake yet. In general, it makes sense to wait at least two days to give people in all timezones the chance to write a comprehensive answer.

Comment: Given that you now prefer @Jörg's answer, and that your question is still warm to the touch, I am surprised that you didn't follow Jörg's advice and merely remove the check-mark from your original selection, rather than moving it to Jörg's answer.   The point is this: there is no rush to select an answer.  Jörg gave the main reason. Here are two more: 1) quick selections reduce the numbers of eyeballs that examine answers for flaws; and 2) it penalizes and annoys readers who are still working on their answers when the greenie flashes up on the screen.

Comment: Playing the newcomer card, I'm still learning the best practices around here. I want to thank you all for the time you took to write such enlightening answers and comments. My behaviour is not representative of who am I and I am deeply grateful for your tutoring. Today I learned more than just ruby. Thank you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to figure out why this works and whether it's a bad practice.

The latter question is hard to answer because your code is so abstract. Also, "bad practice" is opinion-based and thus off-topic.

> The following code will throw a *SyntaxError*:
>
> ```rb
> if true &&
>  puts "ok"
> end
> ```

This is a red herring. Please, read the error message:

```
SyntaxError: unexpected string literal, expecting `do' or '{' or '('
  puts "ok"
       ^
```

It doesn't say anything about the `if`.

I would expect your code to be equivalent to

```rb
if true && puts "ok"
end
```

which indeed raises the same `SyntaxError`:

```
SyntaxError: unexpected string literal, expecting `do' or '{' or '('
if true && puts "ok"
                ^
```

We can further narrow this down to

```rb
true && puts "ok"
```

Which is because `&&` has higher precedence than a whitespace-delimited argument list, and thus this line is parsed as

```rb
(true && puts) "ok"
```

So, to disambiguate, we need to add parentheses to the argument list:

```rb
if true &&
  puts("ok")
end
```

And now the code works as expected.

> Though the following code will not, it will execute as expected:
>
> ```rb
> if true &&
>  if true
>    puts "ok"
>  end
> end
> ```

Indeed, this is perfectly legal. A binary operator at the end of the line will implicitly continue the line, i.e. this code is equivalent to:

```rb
if true && if true
    puts "ok"
  end
end
```

or

```rb
if true && if true then puts "ok" end
end
```

or

```rb
if true && if true then puts "ok" end then end
```

> I came across this while writing a ruby script with an **if** statement

And here is the source of your confusion: this is *not* an `if` statement. This is an `if` *expression*. (Technically, the ISO Ruby Language Specification calls it a *conditional expression*.) There *are no* statements in Ruby, only expressions.

> I was amazed that it didn't because another **if** statement followed right after.

It *isn't* a statement. It is an expression like any other expression. `foo && bar` is perfectly legal and `foo && if true then 23 end` is also perfectly legal *because it is the exact same thing*: an `&&` operator with an expression on either side.

Comment: The point about `if` being an expression is really buried here. Since it is an expression it can be chained, or even used inside other expressions, including an `if`, as bizarre as that seems.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try following,

```
if true &&
  (puts "ok")
end
```

It will not throw error and you will get help to gather conclusion.

Left hand side of `&&` need expression to be executed and when you provide following to left side of `&&`,

```
  if true
    puts "ok"
  end
```

It is considered as single expression.

Perhaps it is executed as, `true.send :&, expression` and here providing `puts 'ok'` as expression surely throw `SyntaxError`