# Simple program but so very stuck- Loops in Ruby

Tags: ruby, loops, iteration, interactive

I have to write a program which asks the user to enter a number.
The program keeps on asking the user for a number until the user types 'Stop'
at which point the sum of the numbers that the user has entered should be printed.
I've tried many,many things and none of my ideas work.
This is what I have - but I can that it isn't correct. What am I doing wrong?

I've only used while loops and arrays

```
total_user_input = []
# As long as the user inputs a number, the program will keep putting Give me a number
# and then adding that number to the total_user_input array.
puts "Give me a number: "
while user_input = gets.chomp.to_i
  #add the input to the array total_user_input
  total_user_input.push(user_input.to_i)
  puts "Give me a number: "
  # If the user however types stop, then the loop is broken and we jump down to the
  # sum bit - where all of the numbers in the total_user_input array are added together
  # and printed. End of program!
  if user_input == "stop"
    break
  end
  sum = 0
  total_user_input.each { |num| 
    sum += num
  }
  puts sum
end
```

The output isn't as it should be.

Comment: The indentation in this code was really inconsistent and the comments were broken up so parts of them looked like code. Fixed that, but do try and keep your examples as clean as possible. It helps with our understanding of the problem.

Comment: Hint: Will you ever get the output of `gets.chomp.to_i` to be `"stop"`?

Comment: Best practice on SO is to not mark the first answer accepted right away as others may provide alternative solutions.

Comment: Further to @lacostenycoder's point, please see the comments on [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57729290/is-there-a-reason-for-an-if-statement-followed-by-another-to-end-the-line-with-a#comment101901092_57729290).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note these few things:

1. `get.chomp.to_i` will convert every input to integer. ("stop" or any non integer string will be 0)
2. Arrangement of the flow is quite messy.

```rb
total_user_input = []

puts "Give me a number: "
while user_input = gets.chomp.strip
  total_user_input.push(user_input.to_i)
  sum = 0
  total_user_input.each { |num| 
    sum += num
  }
  puts sum

  if user_input == "stop"
    break
  end

end
```

Hope you understand this.

Comment: Thank you so much. This was extremely useful. Could I just ask why you have used 'strip'.

Comment: Assuming someone enters "            stop" it'll break the code without the use of `strip`

Comment: @blitzblade right.  However, any program which takes user input should have more thorough "error handling". The way you've "fixed" the OP question does very little to improve the UI except to allow the user to enter accidental space in there "stop" command.

Answer (score 2):

As others have identified the problems with your code let me suggest how you might reorganize it. Ruby provides many ways to execute loops but you many find it desirable to primarily relay on the method [Kernel#loop](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) and the keyword [break](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/doc/keywords_rdoc.html). (As you will learn in time, `loop` is particularly convenient when used with enumerators.)

```
def sum_numbers
  tot = 0
  loop do
    print 'Gimme a number: '
    s = gets.chomp
    break if s == 'Stop'
    tot += s.to_i
  end
  tot
end
```

The keyword `break` can optionally take an argument (though why that is not mentioned in the doc I cannot say), in which case it (if a literal) or its value (if a variable or method) is returned by `loop`. Here one would generally see

```
    break tot if s == 'Stop'
```

without the final line, `tot`. As the loop returns `tot` and that is the last calculation performed by the method, the method will return the final value of `tot`.

You could have instead written

```
return tot if user_input == 'Stop'
```

but I think most coders believe best practice dictates that one should not return from a method from within a loop (or from within nested loops) unless there is a good reason for doing so.

Some small points:

- I used `print` rather than `puts` to that the user's entry will be shown on the same line as the prompt.
- I used `s` (for "string") rather than `user_input` because it reduces the chance of spelling mistakes (e.g., `user_imput`), speeds reading, and (possibly a foible of mine), looks neater. True, `s` is not descriptive, but one only has to remember its meaning for three consecutive lines of code. Others may disagree.
- You could write, `break if s.downcase == 'stop'` if you want, say, `'stop'` or `'STOP'` to have the same effect as `'Stop'`.
- `'23O3'.to_i #=> 23` (that's an an oh, not a zero), so in real life you'd want to confirm that either `'Stop'` or the string representation of a number had been typed.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do this preferring to use `loop do end` syntax with a `break` when it should.  Also added a bit more text so user knows what's happening.

```
total_user_input = []
puts 'Give me a number or "stop" to end: '
loop do
  user_input = gets.chomp
  total_user_input << user_input.to_i
  puts "Give me a number: "
  break if user_input.downcase == "stop"
end
puts "Total entered: #{total_user_input.inject(&:+)}" unless total_user_input.empty?
puts 'goodbye!'
```